# Mobile Tools detects mobile and iPad, not Android tablet

Tags: 6, mobile-tools

I have used the [Mobile Tools](http://drupal.org/project/mobile_tools) module for Drupal 6 to distinguish between mobiles,tablets and browsers. I am not using themes, just provided the redirection urls from the drupal admin settings.

The aim is  to redirect to mobile site while accessing from mobile(mysite.com/mobile). 
Must redirect to the existing site while taken from tablet and web browsers(mysite.com).
It works fine for iphone,andorid mobile,blackberry and iPad.

But it redirects to mobile site when taken from Android tablet while I need to redirect to the desktop url.

Can anybody suggest how can I handle the android tablet using mobile tool so that it does not get redirected to mobile site?

Comment: Is the browscap current?

Comment: When browscap module was added and enabled,the drupal site went down.Therefore,i removed it. is there any provision to forcefully redirect the android tablet users to desktop site using mobile tool?

Comment: Pretty sure D6 module can use a brows cap file if you configure PHP.ini properly. It sounds like you just need updated definitions, but that is just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey)? It has OS based redirection rules. Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional properties exposed by other modules. In combination with Drupal's theme inheritance you can easily achieve features like:
>
> - individually-styled channels
> - a front-page / "splash" screen
> - a date/time-selected Christmas theme
> - mobile themes for different auto-detected mobile devices
> - special themes for "limited" or "old" browsers
> - content, user, or role -specific themes
> - indicating your environment (production, staging, testing, sandbox, … )
> - testing your redesign safely on a live server

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I made some modification in the mobile tool file to work for android tablet and it seems to be okay now.